# Replace duplicates (multiple columns) by group

Tags: r

I'd like to replace all the duplicates by group with NA, only if they are duplicates in 2 columns at the same time, e.g. V2 and V3.

```
V1 V2 V3 V4    
1 a b c d    
2 a c b a  
2 a c b d
```

The end result should be:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4     
1 a b c d  
2 a c b a   
2 na na b d
```

The basic code I'm trying to tweak at the moment is:

```
df %>% 
group_by(V1) %>% 
mutate_each(funs(replace(., duplicated(.), NA)))
```

As you can see, this code works fine with all separate columns, but when I want to try to pass the condition of removing "only if duplicate in 2 columns" (e.g. by `mutate_each(funs(replace(., duplicated(c("V2", "V3"), NA)))` or `mutate_each(funs(replace(., duplicated(df[c("V2", "V3")], NA))))`, it doesn't lead me anywhere.

Any suggestions on how to properly pass multiple columns to duplicated?

Comment: I think you would use `mutate_at()` in that case.

Comment: Tried many times, and whichever way I pass the variables into the whole mutate_at or only duplicated, doesn't work. It seems like mutate_at cannot handle two variables simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to use `mutate_at` that doesn't rely on `duplicated` to achieve the result:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "id V1 V2 V3 V4    
1 a b c d    
2 a c b a  
2 a c b d   ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id, V2, V3) %>%
  mutate(dup_id = row_number()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  mutate_at(vars(V2, V3), funs(if_else(dup_id > 1, NA_character_, .)))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>      id    V1    V2    V3    V4 dup_id
#>   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <int>
#> 1     1     a     b     c     d      1
#> 2     2     a     c     b     a      1
#> 3     2     a  <NA>  <NA>     d      2
```

An alternative approach is to use `unite` and `separate` from the `tidyr` package

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  unite(V2_V3, V2, V3) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(V2_V3), funs(if_else(duplicated(.), NA_character_, .))) %>%
  separate(V2_V3, c("V2", "V3"))

#>   id V1   V2   V3 V4
#> 1  1  a    b    c  d
#> 2  2  a    c    b  a
#> 3  2  a <NA> <NA>  d
```

Comment: Thank you! However, with the 1st approach I get `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: false must be length 26 (length of condition) or one, not 4.`, I think that's because I try to pass group_by before (in my example, V1 refers to ID column, and 2nd and 3rd are the same). I'll see where I can get with the second approach - the problem being that my actual values are words with spaces in between (different structure from col to col), and if I encounter another dataset with a bit different structure of words current solution wouldn't apply.

Comment: You're right @Psych91, the first example is not usable when `group` is used. I've replaced with an alternative that uses `group` but doesn't rely on `duplicated` to achieve the result

Comment: Thanks @markdly, this works! For anyone who will use this code: if you have variables as factors, change them to character first before passing them to if_else here.